# snowflake: unable to alter table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi i have the following tables in a database

[image]

i am trying to move table4 from schema1 to schema2

I am trying

```
alter table if exists "SANTHOSH_TESTING"."SCHEMA1"."table4" RENAME TO "SANTHOSH_TESTING"."SCHEMA2"."table4";
```

it says

```
Statement executed successfully.
```

but nothing happens (i mean the table4 is still in schema1.)

Comment: Thanks to you, I tested RENAME to move tables. And I see that it works as expected. So I wonder if the issue is about async between the tables and the UI?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the object browser?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the 'Find database objects' pane, as the changes will reflect after refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is with small and caps

the correct one is

```
alter table if exists "SANTHOSH_TESTING"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE4" RENAME TO "SANTHOSH_TESTING"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE4";
```